# Styled JSX: dynamic animation for multiple elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, styles

I'm writing a SVG images generator for my React application. The image looks pretty much like a planet: it is a circle which has many ellipses inside. I'm trying to animate them so that they move from right to left, like if this "planet" was rotating. To do this, I would like to assign each ellipse it's own CSS animation, which would be generated dynamically. I would like to use styled-jsx to handle the styles, because I may have lots of these images and I need to namespace them.

This is what my generator looks like (very simplified):

```
function generate() {
  const result = []
  const count = random(8, 12) // lodash 'random' function
  const height = random(40, 60)  

  for(let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    result.push({
      x: random(600),
      y: random(600),
      height,
      width: random(100, 200),
    })
  }
  return result
}
```

What I tried to do:

```
//...
const className = `Ellipse_${i}`
const { className: scopedClassName, styles } = css.resolve`
@keyframes ${className} {
  // claculations for animation
}
.${className} {
  animation: ${className} 15s linear infinite; 
}
`

result.push({
  // ...
  className: `${className} ${scopedClassName}`,
  styles,
})
```

```
// ...
{ellipses.map(({x, y, width, height, className, styles}) => (
  <circle cx={x} cy={y} rx={width} ry={height} fill={'red'} className={className}>
    {styles}
  </circle>
))}
// ...
```

The styles are being created correctly. The problem is that the animation name in the `@keyframes` is being transpiled, and in `animation` is not, so it looks something like this:

```css
@keyframes Ellipse_0-jsx-123456789 {
  // bla bla
}
.Ellipse_0.jsx-123456789 {
  animation: Ellipse_0 15s linear infinite;
}
```

How can I fix this? I guess there must be another simpler way around, but I don't really see it

Comment: I ended up splitting involved styles on local and one `global` style (https://github.com/vercel/styled-jsx#external-styles). Global style - only for animations (e.g. keyframes, selectors, etc.). In this setup name of keyframes, selectors, etc. remains untouched. But you need to make sure that they have long unique prefix.

Comment: Even with global styles there was an issue when animations not bound to HTML elements :0 Ended up pre-calculating animation in JS script and then copy/pasting keyframes to scoped JSX style. In this case animations are working as expected.